# most optimized CSS for browsers

Tags: html, css, optimization, browser

As a web developer, you can only go to a certain amount of effort to optimize your CSS code. However, computers can take into account way more in almost no time and are thus better in optimizing. **The question is: What CSS code is hypothetically the most optimized?** *(for modern browsers)*

Considering the following image: [image]

**A**, **B**, **C** and **D** are DOM-objects (lets say DIV-elements) and the numbers 1-17 represent attributes (like color, background, width, height, etc)

*Whereas all numbers represent a unique attributes. e.g:*

```
4 = background-color: #FF0;    
5 = width: 50px;
10 = background-color: #F00;
```

There are multiple ways you can generate the css code for this web:

**All own ID's**

```
#A { 1 2 5 8 9 10 12 }
#B { 1 4 5 11 12 13 14 15 }
#C { 1 2 3 5 7 }
#D { 3 4 5 6 16 17 }
```

However, the file would be very large, the attributes are not shared and a simple test proofs that this is rather slow to render. *(image1.html, see file generating script below)*

**Share some common attributes**

```
#A { 2 8 9 10 12 }
#B { 4 11 12 13 14 15 }
#C { 2 3 7 }
#D { 3 4 6 16 17 }
.1 { 1 }
.5 { 5 }
```

The file would be smaller and the rendering seems to be quicker. *(see image2.html)*

**Share ALL common attributes**

```
#A { 8 9 10 }
#B { 11 13 14 15 }
#C { 7 }
#D { 6 16 17 }
.1 { 1 }
.3 { 3 }
.2 { 2 }
.4 { 4 }
.5 { 5 }
.12 { 12 }
```

The file would be even smaller (most of the time) and as it turns out the rendering goes quicker as well. But notice that **A**, **B** and **C** end up with one ID, and 4 classes that contain only one attribute! *(see image3.html)*

Now these are three simple examples of CSS code. But as you can imagion, when more DOM objects exist, and more overlap of attributes exist, you could theoretically end up with one DOM object with 1 ID and 10'ths of classes!

**What CSS code is hypothetically the most optimized?** *(for modern browsers)* 
Should you limit the amount of classess per DOM object? should you prefer a "single attribute containing class" over adding it to an ID?

*p.s. **as a test I loaded an image using PHP**. Than read the pixel value of that PNG and create the same picture using CSS and DIV-elements. [The code for generating **image1.html**, **image2.html** and **image3.html** can be found here](http://pastebin.com/DQxiFz5z)*
*You can use ANY PNG image... I used [this image](http://orig05.deviantart.net/e6b7/f/2013/144/f/c/fancy_feonix_by_tatchit-d66d19m.png)*

Comment: I think this topic is too broad as individual has different taste and ways for their own implementation...I think once you reached the general guild lines, then it is up to you how you what it to work...imho

Comment: It has nothing to do with individual taste, since I'm not asking for an opinion but fact based evidence for the most optimized css code. Now this might indeed differ slightly amonst browsers, yet there will most certainly be some agreement

Comment: If you found for a little render CSS it's very difficult. You can have an small css file with SASS or LESS, but it compiles in a standard CSS file that will be as longer as needed. The way to optimize depending on your project and your work way / flow.

Comment: @Jeffrey I don't get your question: you were able to find out that the "share all common attributes" generates the smallest file and is the fastest solution. Then it seems that you think that "A, B and C end up with one ID, and 4 classes that contain only one attribute! " is a minus point for this solution. This is to me a good thing not a bad one.. why are you trying to say that this should be a problem?

Comment: Define "optimized". Smallest code? Fastest parsing time? Easiest to write? Easiest to maintain? Fasted to apply at run-time? The general rule for **all** optimization problems is that you first optimize for clarity and correctness. Then, if you find you have a performance problem in a particular area, you optimize for it. Except in huge websites with thousands of elements and extremely complex rules, I've seen very few cases where CSS is the optimization priority. So I don't think this is an important problem, except if it's an academic exercise.

Comment: @nowhere It is not a bad thing, I just have no proof whatsoever to say that it is the most optimized method. In the testfiles, I figured that resharing a class a couple of thousand times is in fact more optimised than placing it in ID’s. But that is not common for a website. What if you have multiple DOM elements over multiple pages, would you still share them? Should “solo”-shared attributes be placed in its own class? Or perhaps only if you have two+ attributes? How many classes should one append at max, to one DOM element? So many questions, yet I have no idea how to properly test them

Comment: @torazaburo: Assume a website with ALL in-line CSS. Now run a program that reads ALL CSS code, provides ID’s and Classess to the DOM elements and optimizes all CSS code in such a way that it has the: “Fastest parse time”. Since CDS-networks can provide fast transfer, I **think** that the file size is of lesser importance. User maintainability and readability are not important at all.

Comment: So it's parse time, as opposed to the time to apply the rules at run-time, that you want to prioritize? A simplistic approximation would be that parse time is linear in length, meaning that whatever approach compresses/factors/combines rules best would "win". However, such an approach would likely be slower at run time. You have to decide what your priority is. Actually, as I mentioned neither parse time nor apply time is likely to be a good top priority.

Comment: @torazaburo: My apologise for my misunderstanding of the definitions. After some more reading I would like to say that the **runtime is more important to me** than the parse time. However that does not mean that an inefficient parse time should undo the optimisation for the runtime. I agree that proper coding is very important, as well as the fact that the CSS code on its own would most likely not be the bottleneck of the problem, but once again, that’s why this is a hypothetical question :)

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS.

Comment: @torazaburo From the Mozilla CSS guide: "Note: This document was originally written in 2000. Much has changed when it comes to writing CSS that is fast. This guide is not an accurate representation…"

Comment: how do you know it renders faster? how did you test, and where is the data?

Comment: Modern applications use not only a ton of CSS, but also a ton of JavaScript, and they interact with each other. Here and there, JS code adds or removes a class, etc. Also JS inserts whole parts of the DOM tree, possibly based on some JSON received via AJAX, thus making it hard to say how the resulting DOM tree the CSS will be applied to would look like. In your scenario, you need to overwrite the HTML to include the new classes; but is needs to be done with the JS and the JS-generated parts of DOM tree, too.

Comment: Note that there are complex selectors examining the attributes of elements, and you must not change which elements they match (if they examine class), or compensate for the mismatch by adding more rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers should be doing any such optimization internally, as they “compile” the CSS. The compiler is responsible for optimization, because it knows about its implementation details and is able to tell, which fits its needs best.

Programmers can take care only of the things that the compiler is unable to deduce (e.g. due to being unable to solve the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)). Otherwise, writing semantically correct code is their best bet.

This is actually in accordance with what Antti Koivisto, a contributor to WebKit core, said in 2011, having spent some time optimizing its CSS selector matching:

> My view is that authors should not need to worry about optimizing selectors (and from what I see, they generally don’t), that should be the job of the engine.

<sup>Quote via [CSS Selector Performance has changed! (For the better)](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2011/css-selector-performance-has-changed-for-the-better/) by Nicole Sullivan. A good source about modern-day CSS optimization, BTW. The article is referenced in the note at the top of the outdated 2000 article [Writing efficient CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS) by David Hyatt.</sup>

So the concern about [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) expressed by some commenters and shared by me is probably warranted.

Comment: With the bounty due in less than an hour, this is the best answer so far. You have a point, saying that it is the task of the engine to make the rendering as fast as possible, and not the user. Taking into account the link (also provided by torazaburo), it is clear that the correct use of selectors will be of great importance to the speed. To me, one important question is left; is there a limit on amount of selectors to one DOM object before it slows down the process?

Comment: From what I know, the main problem is telling the selectors that match from those that do not. If a selector actually matches, it needs to be examined in its entirety, therefore the overall complexity depends on the complexity of used selectors. (The linked article says adjacency combinators can still be slow.) Moreover, when the selector matches, the associated declarations have to be applied. I’m not sure about the complexity of this step, e.g. because specificity calculation is involved. I guess the overall complexity is proportional to the number of declarations being applied.

Answer (score 7):

you have already answered your own question with the test you created.

@torazaburo has provided good input for your question.

creating IDs and Classes for every shared attribute will speed up your runtime. on the other hand created classes containing the most attributes will speed up parse time.
the problem with both approaches is that if you use this as a rule of thumb, your code will quickly become unreadable and complex to maintain.

this is where your own judgement and work style comes into place.
I don't see a point for creating IDs or Classes for single attributes or Classes for elements that are not repetitive in your DOM, as the load time gain you will experience will be insignificant.

therefore, try to prioritise your CSS optimisation by solving code duplication issues. this will effectively reduce your overall load times and make your code readable and maintainable for the future.

Comment: In the OP's definition of optimization, "[user maintainability and readability are not important at all.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797663/most-optimized-css-for-browsers#comment53726387_32797663)" It appears they are creating a fully generated CSS file on the server that will not be maintained by themselves or other developers. It's an academic question about computational idealism with no basis in human pragmatism.

Comment: @gfullam in that case, the answer is still present in the original post

Comment: Perhaps. But that is just empirical evidence. The OP is "looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources."

Comment: Many questions are still left unknown, for which i'm looking for an answear. see the 'subquestions' in the post, as well as the subquestions in the comments I placed below

Answer (score 0):

One setback I'm thinking of is responsive capability. Let's take for example this code:

HTML:

```
<ul class="overflowHidden blackOnePixelBorder resetPadddingAndMargin noListStyle">
    <li class="backgroundGreen floatLeft threePerRow heightTwoHunderPixels"></li>
    <li class="backgroundRed floatLeft threePerRow heightTwoHunderPixels"></li>
    <li class="backgroundBlue floatLeft threePerRow heightTwoHunderPixels"></li>
    <li class="backgroundRed floatLeft threePerRow heightTwoHunderPixels"></li>
    <li class="backgroundBlue floatLeft threePerRow heightTwoHunderPixels"></li>
    <li class="backgroundGreen floatLeft threePerRow heightTwoHunderPixels"></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.resetPadddingAndMargin {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.noListStyle {
    list-style: none;
}
.overflowHidden {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.blackOnePixelBorder {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.backgroundRed {
    background: #f00;
}
.backgroundGreen {
    background: #0f0;
}
.backgroundBlue {
    background: #00f;
}
.floatLeft {
    float: left;
}
.threePerRow {
    width: 33.33%;
}
.heightTwoHunderPixels {
    height: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bqh8he7e/

How are you gonna resolve the problem of overlapping CSS code or if you want to use one class in different resolutions or devices without overwriting it when you want to have all the squares on one line ? (*without JS)

(I hope I understood your idea)